# How do I keep all sub-menu items open at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle, slidedown, fadeto

I'm going to do my best to articulate this, hopefully it's clear.

I have a nav menu with a series of menu-items. When you hover over a certain menu item, an associated content-area slides down into view. On mouse leave of the content-area, it slides back out of view.

If the the user decides to hover over a different menu-item while one content-area is already open, the second associated content-area slides in to view as well. So in this case, both content areas are still open, stacked on top of each other.

My problem is that if you hover over the upper most content-area, everything is fine, but if you move your cursor down to explore the second content area (both of which are currently open), they both collapse.

My question is, can someone please explain to me what I need to do in order that each open content-area will stay open, regardless of what content-area the user is currently engaging with.

Here's an example of the markup:

```
<ul>
    <li id="menu-item-1">contact</li>
    <li id="menu-item-2">artists</li>
</ul>

<div class="dropdown-contact">
    <p class="big-intro-c">contact</p>
    <div class="row dc-content">
        contact content
    </div> <!-- .row .dc-content -->
</div> <!-- .dropdown-contact-->

<div class="dropdown-artists">
    <p class="big-intro-a">artists</p>
    <div class="row da-content">
        artists content
    </div> <!-- .row .da-content -->
</div> <!-- .dropdown-artists-->
```

And the relative CSS:

```
ul {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

.dropdown-contact, .dropdown-artists {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

.big-intro-c, .big-intro-a {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
}

.dc-content, .da-content {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Here's my .js (apologies - I'm still learning):

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("mouseenter", "#menu-item-1, .dropdown-contact", function () {
        $(".dropdown-contact").stop().slideDown(500, function() {
            $(".big-intro-c").stop().fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
                $(".dc-content").stop().fadeTo(200, 1)
            });
        });
    });

    $("#menu-item-1, .dropdown-contact").not('#menu-item-1').mouseleave(function () {
        $(".dc-content").stop().fadeTo(500, 0, function() {
            $(".dropdown-contact").stop().slideToggle(500, function() {
                $(".big-intro-c").stop().fadeTo(1000, 1)
            });
        });
    });
});

$(function () {
    $(document).on("mouseenter", "#menu-item-2, .dropdown-artists", function () {
        $(".dropdown-artists").stop().slideDown(500, function() {
            $(".big-intro-a").stop().fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
                $(".da-content").stop().fadeTo(200, 1)
            });
        });
    });

    $("#menu-item-2, .dropdown-artists").not('#menu-item-2').mouseleave(function () {
        $(".da-content").stop().fadeTo(500, 0, function() {
            $(".dropdown-artists").stop().slideToggle(500, function() {
                $(".big-intro-a").stop().fadeTo(1000, 1)
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I've included a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LrCTA/8/ though there seems to be some things that I can't mirror from my production site: http://ericbrockmanwebsites.com/ I think what is there, though, does show the issue.

As always, thanks in advance for any insight you may be able to provide.

Comment: Aren't there open-source libraries that already do this sort of thing?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Perhaps, but I like doing it the hard way as it aids my learning. Also, this client has some pretty alternative ideas about how they want things to work (it's for a glitch electronic music label).

Comment: Sure, but you can get some hints about how others made it work by looking at their code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey cheers, maybe that's a good starting point.